# Mocking multiple instances of methods pytest

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, google-cloud-storage, pytest

I have a function that looks roughly like this:

```
import google.cloud.storage
from typing import Optional

def read_from_gcs(bucket_1: Optional[str], bucket_2: str):
    files = []
    if bucket_1 is not None:
        dataset_bucket = google.cloud.storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_1)
        for blob in dataset_bucket.list_blobs():
            files.append(blob.name)

    dataset_bucket_2 = google.cloud.storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_2)
    for blob in dataset_bucket_2.list_blobs():
        if blob.name not in files:
            yield blob.name
```

I want to write unit test for this function with `pytest` and I want to mock the connection to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). I'm struggling with how I can mock `google.cloud.storage.Client().list_blobs()` that is instantiated twice.

If it's only called once, I can do something like:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

@patch("google.cloud.storage.Client")
def test_read_from_gcs(mock_client):

    mock_blobs = [MagicMock() for i in range(3)]
    for mock_blob in mock_blobs:
        mock_blob.configure_mock(name="test.txt", size=3)
    mock_blobs[0].name = "test_0.txt"
    mock_client.return_value.get_bucket.return_value.list_blobs.return_value = mock_blobs
    assert mock_blobs[1].name in next(read_from_gcs(bucket_2="bucket_2"))
```

But now I want to extend the case by testing the `if` statement where `bucket_1` is provided and I'm struggling how I can mock multiple instances of `Client().list_blobs()`.

Thank you

Comment: Good opportunity to refactor and instantiate the client only once

Comment: Why do you want to mock the connection to GCS? If you do so, you're not testing your integration works properly. If the library changes in some way, your test may not fail because it doesn't accurately represent what the real client is doing. That's alone enough of a reason to not mock classes, etc. from external libraries.

Comment: Do you already have an integration test for your function? If so, why do you want a unit test also?